# Problema ao atualizar um lista após inserir um dado por outra pagina

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Tenho uma página que possui uma lista com os nomes de "alunos" cadastrados em determinado curso. Logo em seguida, clico em um botão de adicionar. Esse botão leva à uma tela com todos os nomes dos "alunos". A intenção é clicar em um dos nome e então fechar esta tela e atualizar a lista da primeira tela. Porém não estou conseguindo.

Como posso corrigir isso?

**Minha estrutura**

1. **Listar Aluno:** Essa pagina tem um botão que da um Navigator.push para a AdicionarAlunoScreen passando o id do grupo em que a lista pertence;
2. **AdicionarAlunoScreen:** O corpo dela tem a pagina de consulta `ConsultarAluno(Ela recebe o id também)`.

A página consultar aluno possui o seguinte `FutureBuild`:

```
return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: Firestore.instance.collection("alunos").getDocuments(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      var divideTiles = ListTile.divideTiles(
          tiles: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) {
            return AlunosTile(doc,widget.id);
          }).toList(),
          color: Colors.grey[500])
          .toList();

      return ListView(
        children: divideTiles,
      );
    }
  }
```

Esse `FutureBuild` constroi a lista de todos os alunos cadastrados, e quando seleciono um aluno ele grava no banco o nome desse aluno e volta para a tela anterior onde tem apenas os alunos cadastros naquele grupo. Porém essa atualização no banco de dados ocorre, mas na tela nada muda. Para carregar a lista preciso voltar uma tela e ver todos os detalhes do grupo, e clicar no botão de listar aluno de novo, dessa forma o documento atualiza.

O que estava tentando fazer é quando clicar no aluno e adicionar ele no grupo, a tela que mostra os alunos cadastrados se atualizar com o aluno que selecionei na tela seguinte.

Seguem os códigos :

```
class _ListarAlunosState extends State<ListarAlunos> {


@override 

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text("Lista"),  

actions: <Widget>[
  

IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.group_add),
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        AdicionarAlunoScreen(widget.snapshot.documentID)));

          }),
    ],

  ),
  body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: Firestore.instance
          .collection("trabalhos")
          .document(widget.snapshot.documentID)
          .collection("alunos")
          .getDocuments(),
      builder: (context, snapshotAluno) {
        if (!snapshotAluno.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshotAluno.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshotAluno.data.documents[index];
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    Text(
                      doc.data["nome"],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    )
                  ],
                );
              });
        }
      }),
);
  }
}


class AdicionarAlunoScreen extends StatelessWidget {  

String id;



AdicionarAlunoScreen(this.id); 

 @override  

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Adicionar Aluno"),
),
body: ConsultaAlunos(id),
);


 }
}



class ConsultaAlunos extends StatelessWidget {



String nome;


ConsultaAlunos(this.nome);


@override


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: Firestore.instance.collection("alunos").getDocuments(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      var divideTiles = ListTile.divideTiles(
          tiles: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) {
            return AlunosTile(doc,nome);
          }).toList(),
          color: Colors.grey[500])
          .toList();

      return ListView(
        children: divideTiles,
      );
    }
  },
);


 }
}
```

---

```
class AlunosTile extends StatefulWidget {
final DocumentSnapshot snapshot;
String id;
AlunosTile(this.snapshot,this.id);
@override
_AlunosTileState createState() => _AlunosTileState();
}
class _AlunosTileState extends State<AlunosTile> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListTile(
  title: Text(widget.snapshot.data["nome"],
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
leading: Icon(Icons.person_add),
  onTap: (){
    print(widget.snapshot.documentID);
    Firestore.instance.collection("trabalhos").document(widget.id).collection("alunos").add({
      "nome" : widget.snapshot.data["nome"]});
  },
   );
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil, vote e marque como `resposta aceita`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troca os `FutureBuilder` utilizados por um `StreamBuilder`

> Antes

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: Firestore.instance
      .collection("trabalhos")
      .document(widget.snapshot.documentID)
      .collection("alunos")
      .getDocuments(),
  builder: (context, snapshotAluno) {
    // Seu código
  }
)
```

> Depois

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance
    .collection("trabalhos")
    .document(widget.snapshot.documentID)
    .collection("alunos").snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    // Seu código
  }
)
```

Fazendo dessa forma a lista irá se atualizar automaticamente, quando houver qualquer mudança na sua base do Firestore.

**Explicação**

Explicando a grosso modo... O `StreamBuilder` fica "ouvindo" as mudanças que ocorrem no seu banco Firestore, então toda vez que algo mudar lá, o `StreamBuilder` vai receber um novo *snapshot* com os dados atualizados e assim sua lista é atualizada automaticamente!

Então se você fizer a mudança que sugeri, após você inserir o nome do aluno no grupo que está sendo "ouvido" pelo `StreamBuilder`, a lista será atualizada sozinha, você não precisa fazer mais nada.

Comment: Obrigado , funcionou agora entendi o motivo Vlw